# apt-get update isn't able to connect to the internet

Tags: networking, apt, package-management, updates, repository

EDIT: Thankyou for your help @DavidFoerster - not sure how pastie service works but hoefully people will find the output of `sudo apt-get update` here:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/25812862/

EDIT: This was marked as a duplicate. However, I did everything suggested in both suggested articles and it didn't work. The results of it not working can be seen towards the end of the article. Even though I tried everything and it didn't work it still got marked as a duplicate. Did the person not see my additions or am I missing something because as far as I know I've tried everything suggested and it still doesn't work so it surely can't be a duplicate right?

I've done a fair bit of searching and can't find anything that works. Here's what I've tried.

I'm using Ubuntu MATE 1.12.1 and whether I use "software & updates" or `sudo apt-get update` I can't seem to connect to the repos.

I have used the main server and UK server in "software & updates" but when it says:

> The information about available software is out-of-date
>
> To install software and updates from newly added or changed sources, you have to reload the information about available software.
>
> You need a working Internet connection to continue.

I press "reload" and it says:

> Failed to download repository information
>
> Check your Internet connection.

ADDED:
The details tab reveals:

```
W:The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-security Release' does not have a Release file., W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., W:The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-updates Release' does not have a Release file., W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., W:The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-backports Release' does not have a Release file., W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., E:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80], E:Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-backports/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80], E:Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80], E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

From the command-line (again I can't show the output because it has too many links in so here is a shortened example:

```
sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 <LINK> trusty InRelease
Ign:2 <LINK> wily InRelease
...
W: <LINK>: Signature by key 824A27DD09DEDA33BF7835962EA8F35793D8809A uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: The repository '<LINK> wily Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository '<LINK> wily-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository '<LINK> wily-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository '<LINK> wily-security Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch <LINK>  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch <LINK>  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch <LINK>  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch <LINK>  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My internet seems to be working fine: I can surf the web and ping google.

```
oli@oli-Lenovo-G580:~$ ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (216.58.204.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from par10s28-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.204.100): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=28.4 ms
64 bytes from par10s28-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.204.100): icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=27.4 ms
64 bytes from par10s28-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.204.100): icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=27.2 ms
64 bytes from par10s28-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.204.100): icmp_seq=4 ttl=52 time=25.4 ms
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 25.489/27.172/28.499/1.092 ms
```

I also tried the last IP address in the previous code segement and connected fine:

```
oli@oli-Lenovo-G580:~$ ping 91.189.88.161
PING 91.189.88.161 (91.189.88.161) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 91.189.88.161: icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=26.6 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.88.161: icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=27.4 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.88.161: icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=144 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.88.161: icmp_seq=4 ttl=51 time=195 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.88.161: icmp_seq=5 ttl=51 time=123 ms
^C
--- 91.189.88.161 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 26.689/103.440/195.047/66.537 ms
```

I've done all these things with both wireless and wired connection and seemed to get the same/similar result.

Here's some info that people might find useful:

```
oli@oli-Lenovo-G580:~$ dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 2009
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     153 IN  A   216.58.204.14

;; Query time: 13 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Oct 18 11:22:16 BST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```

I would show the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` but it won't let me because it has too many links.

Can anyone help with this please?

ADDITION:
A couple of people mentioned potential duplicates.

1.
[How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

I do not wanted to use unsupported releases and so I tried
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
This gave me the same results of just `sudo apt-get update` and so I tried just `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` which completes without error. Running `sudo apt-get update` again has no change.

Next I tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

The first had no change the second I ran fine and the third:

```
oli@oli-Lenovo-G580:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

Running `sudo apt-get update` results in the same output.

2. [Xenial repository does not have a Release file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/xenial-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file)

   - `sudo ppa-purge ppa:mc3man/trusty-media` looks similar to if I do `sudo apt-get update` and the last line says `Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason`
   - `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/xerus-media` Seems to work fine.
   - After reading the comments below this answer I then went to software & updates and in the "Other software" tab unticked anything with Wily or Trusty in the name. When I closed I got:

   The information about available software is out-of-date

   To install software and updates from newly added or changed sources, you have to reload the information about available software.

   You need a working Internet connection to continue.

Clicked "reload" and got:

```
Failed to download repository information

Check your Internet connection.
```

Runnning `sudo apt-get update` seems to have no effect.

Comment: You appear to be using at lest some repositories from Wily - which is beyond EOL. See [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: @Liso because I don't have enough rep.

Comment: @ojunk: URLs in code sections aren't counted towards the link limit.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the *full, verbatim* output of `sudo apt-get update`? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thank you for the help so far. When I try to add the output of `sudo apt-get update` it says I exceed the body text limit of 30,000 characters. Is there any way around this or should I cut out some lines in the middle or something?

Comment: Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your mirrors are messed up. This happened to me a while ago and I edited my `/etc/apt/sources.list` and tried different mirrors and it worked. I read about a new feature that automatically selects the right mirror based on your location, try putting this on top of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

```
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: Tried this and it didn't work.